# class attribute in goog.dom.createDom('input', 'class': 'xyz') not working in firefox while it works in chrome

Tags: google-closure-library

When i use  goog.dom.createDom('input', 'class': 'xyz') in my js file, the style applied to my class is not applied when run in firefox while it works in chrome.Here is the code:

```
var checkBox = goog.dom.createDom('input', {'type': 'checkbox'});
var checkBoxDiv = goog.dom.createDom('div', {'class': 'checkbox'}, checkBox);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS must be wrong. Your code will give you the following without fail, which I'm sure you can see by debugging:

```
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></div>
```